# get elementbyId in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to access an HTML tag in my .js file. 
In html page, I'm having `<p class="postBodyText" ng-attr-id="myHeader"></p>` 
and In js page,

```
console.log(document.getElementById("myHeader"));
```

I'm getting **null** as output. Please help me.

Comment: `console.log(angular.element('p[ng-attr-id="myHeader"]'));`

Comment: or you can just do `angular.element('.postBodyText');`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got that, my code is working but not in the first time, it works in the second time, which means html elements of that views are not loaded at the time of js initialize. Now how to solve that problem....

Comment: okay. In that case, you're gonna have to look for DOMContentLoaded event by doing `angular.element(document).ready(function () {console.log(angular.element('p[ng-attr-id="myHeader"]'));});`

Comment: will you please elaborate more

Comment: by using the `angular.element(document).ready(function () {console.log(angular.element('p[ng-attr-id="myHeader"]'));});`, I'm getting an error `Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel]`

Comment: Try `angular.element('document')` instead if `angular.element(document)`. (document is in quotes). I don't see why it would change anything but give it a go.

Comment: hey, sorry for late reply, but this also not working. Getting the same error. I tried `angular.element('document')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the directive linking function you can use id of attributes:

```
link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
   var id = attrs.id;
   console.log(id);
}
```

Or, this may be your solution:

```
<p class="postBodyText" ng-attr-id="{{'myHeader'}}"></p>
```

Which renders the html like this:

```
<p class="postBodyText" id="myHeader"></p>
```

Comment: how to use that link function..?? will you please elaborate more about that.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove ng-attr- in front of ng-attr-id if you don't need it it will work fine.

Else try this

```
document.querySelector('[ng-attr-id]')
```

Comment: hey, by using `document.querySelector('[ng-attr-id]')` I am getting `[object HTMLParagraphElement]`. To read that object i am using `document.querySelector('[ng-attr-id]').innerHTML`, nut not able to parse the object. Please help

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the element you got. Can you explain what you want to extract from that element.